# APIM - Updating Named value parameter with api response

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I am new to APIM and got a scenario. I have multiple apis. But all require authentication. The authentication api works fine. I want to capture the token from authentication api response and pass that as a header into subsequent apis.

I have created a named value parameter say authTokenValue and I need to update that with auth token response. Response is like below

```
 "userId":"test",
 "meta":{
    "authToken": "tokenValue",
    ----
  }
}
```

I need to capture authToken value from response and place into named parameter "authTokenValue".

Also- is there any global variable into APIM? If yes then is it good idea to store authToken Value into that?

Any help will be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your scenario, but APIM does not allow you to change named value from inside request, the only way to do so is through management API call. Maybe what you're looking for is cache, you can use caching policies to store data and share it between requests.